# GMFBridge issue with Bgrdge graph

Tags: visual-c++, directshow, video-capture

I am having capture graph application which captures mp4 capture video , i want to use GMFbridge in that, i build my graph as below

First Graph

```
Video Source --> x264vfw - H.264/MPEG-4 AVC Codec -->  GMFBridge Sink Filter -->
```

Second Graph

```
 --> GMF Source Filter -->  GDCL Mux --> Filter Writer
```

All filters are get connected as per above graph , but when i call BridgeGraph method of GMFBridge to connect two graphs , it is giving me

```
error : A subscription cannot be stored unless its event class already exists any idea
```

is there anything wrong with this combination should i use different combination?? or there's some other issue??

Please Help me...

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Issue is resolved , i was rendering only video stream and i added control for both audio and video stream for `GMFBridge Controller` , so i removed stream for audio and my issue is resolved.

Whoever have this issue , please crosscheck that your application is redering the stream which is added using `m_pBridge.AddStream()` method ,